# Android Widget ( Stopwatch, start,stop and reset button ) doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast, android-handler

I'm creating "start", "stop" and "reset" button for stopwatch android widget.

1. Stopwatch widget is able to show while start ,stop button doesn't work properly. when click start button, timer is start running, but unable to stop.

Below, is my Main.java

```
public class Main extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

    Intent buildButtonIntent = new Intent();
    buildButtonIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.UPDATE");
    buildButtonIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, buildButtonIntent, 0);

    Intent stopButtonIntent = new Intent();
    stopButtonIntent.setAction("android.intent.action.UPDATEd");
    stopButtonIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
    PendingIntent stopButtonPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, stopButtonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, buildButtonPendingIntent );   
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, stopButtonPendingIntent );
    Toast.makeText(context, "wei...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }
}
```

follow by Broadcast.java

```
    public class Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

    private static int clickCount = 0;
    private Button btnstart;
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    private long startTime = 0L;
    long timeInMillies = 0L;
    long timeSwap = 0L;
    long finalTime = 0L;
    private boolean stopped = false;
    private boolean start_running = true;
    TextView textTimer;
    RemoteViews remoteViews;
    private int REFRESH_RATE = 100;
    ComponentName widget;
    AppWidgetManager awManager;


    private Runnable startStopwatch = new Runnable(){

        public void run(){

            if(stopped){
            timeInMillies =SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-startTime;
            finalTime=timeSwap+timeInMillies;

            int seconds=(int)(finalTime/1000);
            int minutes=seconds/60;
            int hours = minutes/60;
            seconds=seconds%60;
            int milliseconds = (int)(finalTime%1000);

            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, String.format("%02d : %02d : %02d", hours, minutes, seconds));
            if(stopped){
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, REFRESH_RATE);
            awManager.updateAppWidget(widget, remoteViews);
            }else{

                finalTime=0;
                timeSwap=0;

                myHandler.removeCallbacks(startStopwatch);
                awManager.updateAppWidget(widget, remoteViews);

            }

            }
        }
    };


    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
        widget = new ComponentName(context, Main.class);
        awManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);

        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.UPDATE")){

            startTime=SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            stopped = true;
            start_running = false;
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1,null );
            myHandler.postDelayed(startStopwatch, REFRESH_RATE);
            awManager.updateAppWidget(widget, remoteViews);
            Toast.makeText(context, "start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{
            if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.UPDATEd"))

            timeSwap += timeInMillies;
            stopped = false;
            start_running = false;
            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, null);
            myHandler.removeCallbacks(startStopwatch);
            awManager.updateAppWidget(widget, remoteViews);
            Toast.makeText(context, "stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have got problem with that. 
You can not hold reference for remote view, in broadcast receiver. on each loop you must create remote view over and over. 
I am using for that alarm manager and set time interval to 10 milisecond

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
 calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());          
 calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 10);           
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 10, createClockIntent(context, 1, TIMER_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE));
```

and crete clock intent its simple pending intent for your broadcast receiver. 
I know that widget its not good idea, create stopwatch as widget.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback, but i'm not really understand what do you mean by i can't hold reference for remote view? Do you mean i hold it at Running loop?

Comment: Yes, you can not hold it at running loop, its realy bad idea.
I am creating stopwatch for widget, and i try many different solution. But its only one solution works for that : http://pastebin.com/vr0Ew5U1

Comment: I see, there is quite good stopwatch widget that made in playstore call "stopwatch".

Comment: thanks, i will check it out your code later. current solving bug for another issue .omg is drive me crazy on debugging..hehe

Comment: Sory its my old solution you must use in this case android SystemClock this is good solution : http://pastebin.com/EWEUbi0w